Android Studio: Unable to find valid certification path to requested target
I'm using Android Studio 3.5 with API 23 and using the Pepper SDK Plug in with no version of Java currently installed prior to downloading 3.5 (I was told that android studio downloads all its required stuff)
I'm using a fresh windows install but when I launch Android Studios my Gradle throws:

ERROR: Cause: unable to find valid certification path to requested target.

I'm not using a proxy and I get this issue on my home Wi-Fi and at my universities Wi-Fi.
I've tried changing the repository but this just creates more errors:
repositories {
   maven { url "http://jcenter.bintray.com"}
}

I've tried saving a root CA certificate however I have issues when trying to update my trust store and importing the certificate using the command:
keytool -importcert -alias my-root-ca-cert -file "<Path to saved top cert>\my-root-ca-cert.cer" -keystore "C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\lib\security\cacerts" -storepass changeit -noprompt

However I get the issue:

Keytool is not recognised as command

